# Recursively and asynchronously check if html element exists

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion

I am interacting with a webpage whereby some of the deeper nested elements within sub-frames load even after the document is ready - i.e. they rely on pending ajax/api requests that are yet to be completed when the document is loaded.

My intention is to wait until these elements exist prior to doing anything with them. I can do this using setTimeout and wait for an arbitrary amount of time before doing anything e.g.

```
setTimeout(function() {
      $("#better_content .binder__toc").append(
        "<h4>Experiments</h4><ul><li>This</li><li>is</li><li>a</li><li>test</li></ul>"
      );
    }, 5000);
```

However, it would be nice in a recursive and asynchronous (non-blocking) manner to keep checking for said element ("#better_content .binder__toc") until undefined or null is not returned i.e. the element exists. I have tried to do this using Promises. A simple example with a counter is as follows:

```
static waitForElement = counter => {

   counter++

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      if (counter < 5) {
        this.waitForElement(counter)
          .then(function() {
            res("complete");
          })
          .catch(rej);
      }
      res("complete");
    });
  };

this.waitForElement(counter)
      .then(a => console.log(a))
      .catch(a => console.log(a));
```

The above resolves successfully and appears to be non-blocking. However, if I replace the counter for the element selector as below:

```
static waitForElement = selector => {        

    let found = $(document).find(selector)[0];        
    console.log(found);

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      if (found === undefined) {
        this.waitForElement(selector)
          .then(function() {
            res("found");
          })
          .catch(rej);
      }
      res("found");
    });
  };


this.waitForElement("#better_content .binder__toc")
      .then(a => {
        console.log(a);
        $("#better_content .binder__toc").append(
          "<h4>Experiments</h4><ul><li>This</li><li>is</li><li>a</li><li>test</li></ul>"
        );
      })
      .catch(a => console.log(a));
```

Then this never seems to resolve successfully and really slows down the webpage - I assume as it is blocking the main thread still.

Any suggestions on how I can correct or understand what is going on here would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for changes in an element, or children of an element, with the [`Mutation Observer API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). The API fires a callback in which you can assert your logic to act when a certain change in the element is happened. In your case you'll want to listen on the container where the element is appended to with the `fetch` request.

It is possible to listen for certain changes, like attribute changes, or in your case changes in the children. In the configuration add `childList: true` which will indicate that you want to do something whenever a child is added or removed.

This way you don't have to check in if the element exists.
Check out the example below to see your example in action.

```js
const target = document.getElementById('container');
const config = { childList: true };
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations, observer) => {

  /**
   * Loop through all changes
   */
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    
    /**
     * Only act if it is a change in the children.
     */
    if (mutation.type !== 'childList') {
      return;
    }
  
    /**
     * Loop through the added elements and check if 
     * it is the correct element. Then add HTML to 
     * the newly added element.
     */
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
      if (node.id === 'content') {
        const html = `
          <h4>Experiments</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>This</li>
            <li>is</li>
            <li>a</li
            ><li>test</li>
          </ul>`;
        node.innerHTML = html;
      }
    });
    
    // Stop observing.
    observer.disconnect();
    
  });
  
});

// Observe the children in container.
observer.observe(target, config);

// Add content element after 2 seconds.
setTimeout(function() {
  const content = document.createElement('div');
  content.id = 'content';
  target.append(content);
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```